# Unable to figure out the logic of this usage

Tags: algorithm, optimization

I have two arrays, A and B of same size (say, k) and I need to find the nth smallest sum of one value from A and one value from B. For eg, let
A is [1,2,3] and B is [4, 5, 6].There are 9 elements in the set of sums :

1+4=5;

2+4=6;

1 + 5 = 6;

1 + 6 = 7;

2 + 5 = 7;

3 + 4 = 7;

2 + 6 = 8;

3 + 5 = 8;

3 + 6 = 9;

If I need to find the 4th smallest sum, my answer is 7. 
A naive solution involving a double-loop is easy to find, but I came across this code for the double-loop:

```
sort(a+1,a+k+1);
sort(b+1,b+k+1);
for(i=1; i<=k; i++)
{
        n=10001/i;     //WHY THIS LINE
        ind=min(k,n);   //WHY THIS LINE
        v=a[i];
        for(j=1; j<=ind; j++)
        {
            vc.push_back((v+b[j]));
        }
}
```

I'm unable to understand the use of that 'n' here which I guess is some kind of optimization as without this 'n', the rest of the solution is naive. Also, I'm not sure if it's important, but the constraints of n are

1 <= k <= 10000

Hope somebody can help.

Source: A problem from CodeChef - [LOWSUM](https://www.codechef.com/problems/LOWSUM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All this is saying is:

"If the `k`-th smallest sum (with `k<=10000`) is made of `a[i]+b[j]` for some given `i`, then `j` can not be bigger than `(k+1)/i`, so it can't be bigger than `10001/i` either". So you just don't look for a `j` bigger than `(10001)/i` to associate with a given `i`.

This is because you know that the smallest `i` values in `a`, associated with the `(k+1)/i` values in `b`, will already give you at least `k+1` possible sums, all smaller than the ones made with `a[i]` and `b[j>(k+1)/i]`

Obviously `j` should not be bigger than `k` either, since all the `a[i]+b[j<=q]` would be smaller. So `j` must be smaller than `min(k, 10001/i)`.

(I haven't properly checked my cases of equality, the +1 that are needed or not, etc, but the idea is here).

Comment: This is what I understand now: since we would need at most 10,000 values of n, which implies  i*j < 10001 which implies that j < 10001/i in any case. But if we give 10001/i as the limit for j in the for-loop directly, smaller values of i would result in assigning a value greater than k to j, which should not happen. Hence, we take the minimum of k and 10001/i and assign it to j. Thanks!